# How to convert json to xml usin npm packages whic is jsontoxml

Tags: javascript, json, xml, npm

I want to convert json to xml. I already have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js npm package. Its output like :

```
    <0>
    <name>Autofac</name>
    <version>
        <Version>4.9.0.0</Version>
        <SpecialVersion/>
    </version>
    <ProjectName>PIWorks.Son.UI.Migrations</ProjectName>
    <licenseFile>C:\PIWorks\PISon.UI\licenses\NuGet\Autofac@4.9.0LICENSE.txt</licenseFile>
    <repository>https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</repository>

</0>
```

But I want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontoxml

When I used this packages output like this:

```
<System.Threading.Timer/><System.ValueTuple/><System.Xml.ReaderWriter/><System.Xml.XDocument/><WebGrease/><YUICompressor.NET/>
```

I cannot understand anything what I am wrong.

Its also my json:

```
 {
    "name":  "Autofac",
    "version":  {
                    "Version":  "4.9.0.0",
                    "SpecialVersion":  ""
                },

    "repository":  "https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php"
}
```

I need a help.

Comment: I have tried your son with this package & it works: https://repl.it/repls/RustyCompatibleOpposites. May be you should uninstall & reinstall the package.

Comment: I realised that my json `[ {
    "name":  "Autofac",
    "version":  {
                    "Version":  "4.9.0.0",
                    "SpecialVersion":  ""
                },

    "repository":  "https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php"
} ]` in square bracket .Therefore its wrong .@Juky thanks.